# How to group by condition and average only if column value is not null in bigquery sql

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I have a table that shows the category of product and another table with daily price of the product. I would like to get the average price of the category where average not count null values. How do I achieve this? Example of table product

| product | category |
| --- | --- |
| apple | fruit |
| pear | fruit |
| grape | fruit |
| celery | vegetables |
| cabbage | vegetables |
| chicken | meat |
| turkey | meat |
| beef | meat |

another table with daily price and productid as columns and the price in  the rows

| date | apple | pear | grape | celery | cabbage | chicken | turkey | beef |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 |  | 4 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 2022-01-02 |  |  | 2 | 2 | 2 |  | 4 | 3 |
| 2022-01-03 | 2 |  |  | 2 | 2 |  |  | 3 |

into

| date | fruit | vegetables | meat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 3 | 1.5 | 3.3 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 | 2 | 3.5 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 | 2 | 3 |

Where average is only to columns where it is not null, it would be better not to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below query using **UNPIVOT** AND **PIVOT**:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT date, category, price 
    FROM prices UNPIVOT (price FOR productid IN (apple, pear, grape, celery, cabbage, chicken, turkey, beef)) p
    JOIN category c ON c.product = p.productid
) PIVOT (AVG(price) FOR category IN ('fruit', 'vegetables', 'meat'))
ORDER BY date;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider also below approach

```
create temp function keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
""";
create temp function values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
""";
select *
from (
  select date, category, round(avg(safe_cast(price as float64)), 2) avg_price
  from prices t, unnest([struct(to_json_string(t) as json)]),
  unnest(keys(json)) product with offset
  join unnest(values(json)) price with offset using(offset)
  left join products using(product)
  where product != 'date'
  group by date, category
)
pivot (any_value(avg_price) for category IN ('fruit', 'vegetables', 'meat'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Potential benefit of using above is to eliminate need in enlisting all column names from products table, which are 8 in your example but in reality most likely much more! Obviously, another way to address this is to build dynamic query and run it using `execute immediate` which you can find quite a number of examples here on SO.
But, assuming that number of categories is significantly lower (just few as in your example) to compare with number of products - I would use this approach as `execute immediate` has its own drawbacks ...